# Transpose columns to rows SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, unpivot

How to dynamically transpose some columns to rows if the columns I want to convert to rows all start with a prefix of 'c' in the column name. I have a table as follows

```
DECLARE @t codes 
(
  Tax CHAR(5),
  ptype CHAR(2),
  c1 CHAR(1),
  c2 char(1),
  c3 char(1)
)

insert into @t (tax, ptype, c1, c2, c3) values ('AAAAA','10',Null, 1,2)
insert into @t (tax, ptype, c1, c2, c3) values ('BBBBB','21',3, 1,NULL)
insert into @t (tax, ptype, c1, c2, c3) values ('ZZZZZ','1',NULL, NULL, 2)
insert into @t (tax, ptype, c1, c2, c3) values ('CCCCC',NULL,1,3,4)
insert into @t (tax, ptype, c1, c2, c3) values ('YYYYY','4',NULL, NULL, NULL)
insert into @t (tax, ptype, c1, c2, c3) values ('DDDDD','8',2,5,6)
```

How do I output the below where ptype is not 'NULL' and when c1,c2,c3 are not 'NULL' with C1,C2,C3 values sorted ascending?

```
Tax   ptype  Columns value
----- -----  ------- -----
AAAAA 10     c2      1
AAAAA 10     c3      2 
BBBBB 21     c2      1
BBBBB 21     c1      3 
ZZZZZ 1      c3      2
DDDDD 8      c1      2 
DDDDD 8      c2      5
DDDDD 8      c3      6
```

Comment: Your output is not at all clear. Do you want the literal values 'C2' etc. If you can explain your output clearly we can help.

Comment: @SeanLange I want the column name in 'Columns'. I will edit the OP to clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Query

```
SELECT Tax 
      ,ptype
      ,[Columns]
      ,Value 
   FROM @t
     UNPIVOT (Value FOR Columns IN ( C1 , C2 , C3 ))up
```

### Result Set

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║  Tax  ║ ptype ║ Columns ║ Value ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ AAAAA ║ 10    ║ c2      ║     1 ║
║ AAAAA ║ 10    ║ c3      ║     2 ║
║ BBBBB ║ 21    ║ c1      ║     3 ║
║ BBBBB ║ 21    ║ c2      ║     1 ║
║ ZZZZZ ║ 1     ║ c3      ║     2 ║
║ CCCCC ║ NULL  ║ c1      ║     1 ║
║ CCCCC ║ NULL  ║ c2      ║     3 ║
║ CCCCC ║ NULL  ║ c3      ║     4 ║
║ DDDDD ║ 8     ║ c1      ║     2 ║
║ DDDDD ║ 8     ║ c2      ║     5 ║
║ DDDDD ║ 8     ║ c3      ║     6 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

If you want to eliminate nulls from the result set just add where clause to the above query

```
WHERE [Columname] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do this using `CROSS APPLY` and `table valued constructor` to unpivot the data

```
SELECT tax, 
       ptype, 
       columns, 
       value 
FROM   @t 
       CROSS apply (Select 'c1',c1 
                    UNION ALL 
                    Select 'c2',c2 
                    UNION ALL
                    Select 'c3',c3 ) cs(columns, value) 
WHERE  ptype IS NOT NULL 
       AND columns IS NOT NULL 
       AND value IS NOT NULL
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff5eb/2)

Comment: Thanks @Indian but I am on SQL serve 2005 and I believe CROSS apply does not work

Comment: @user176047 cross apply was introduces in 2005 so it should work as long as your database compatibility level is set to 90.

Comment: @user176047 - Ali is correct. `Cross apply` is introduced in 2005. But the problem is `table valued constructor` which is introduced in 2008. Updated the code check now. This is why you should add proper **tags** to your question

Comment: I find it much easier doing it with UNPIVOT since the syntax was introduced for situations like this one ;)